# encontrar el elemento de la mitad en string

Tags: javascript, string

estoy haciendo problemas de Javascript para entender mejor, mi consigna es crear una función que recibe un string y devuelve el elemento de la mitad del string, independientemente de su longitud.

```
 function midleCharacter(str){
         let arr = [];
         for(let i of str){
          arr.push(i)
          }
         console.log(arr)
}
midleCharacter("cosas")
```

alguien que me oriente un poco, se lo agradeceria mucho. Gracias

Comment: Lo que necesitas es saber calcular el valor medio del string y volverlo parte del algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un código bastante simplificado para hacerlo:

```
function middleCharacter(str) {
    const position = Math.round(str.length / 2) - 1;
    return str.charAt(position);
}

middleCharacter('Javier'); // v
middleCharacter('Nadia'); // d
```

Comment: Intenta siempre utilizar funciones nativas de Javascript, por ejemplo, charAt() lo que hace es coger el carácter de un string mediante su posición índice. Y Math.round () redondea valores. De esa forma he podido sacar la posición del string de en medio dividiendo la longitud del string entre 2 y luego restando 1 porque en caso de que un número decimal acabe en .5 redondea hacía arriba. Espero haberte sido de ayuda ;) @Gualbert Dev

Comment: si pense en convertirlo primero en array y luego dividirlo pero no sabia como, gracias¡

Comment: Para ello tienes la función .split() te dejo aquí un [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) para que puedas testearla. Recuerda, si te ha servido marca la respuesta como correcta y súmale un voto, de esa forma contribuyes a la comunidad para que otras personas utilicen la respuesta, y también me ayudas a crecer a mí, un saludo! @GualbertDev

Answer (score 1):

Esta es otra manera:

```
function midleCharacter(str) {
  return str[Math.floor(str.length / 2)];
}
```

Con los Strings se pueden utilizar varios métodos que aplican para arrays, por lo tanto se puede acceder a la posición del caracter directamente como si fuera un array, ej: str[3], sería el índice 3, o sea el cuarto caracter, considerando que los array comienzan con índice 0.

Dicho esto en la función sencillamente accedemos a la posición que corresponde a la mitad del .length de str y lo redondeamos hacia abajo con el Math.floor para los casos que da un número con decimales, ejemplo en 5 caracteres, la mitad sería 2.5. Dependiendo de que caracter desees o consideres el medio podrías agregarle un -1 a la ecuación si lo consideras necesario.

Basado en tu razonamiento, esto puede funconar:

```
function midleCharacter(str) {
  let midleResult = "";
  const midleCharIndex = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
  str.length % 2 === 0
    ? (midleResult = str[midleCharIndex - 1] + str[midleCharIndex])
    : (midleResult = str[midleCharIndex]);
  return midleResult;
}
```

Quedo a las órdenes.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la ayuda solucione mi problema, recibo un string y si es par regresa los elementos que estan en la mitad por decirlo de esa forma, si no es par, devuelve solo un elemento, me ayudo mucho la ayuda que me proporcionaron, el codigo quedo asi:

```
function midleCharacter(str) {
 const position = Math.round(str.length / 2) -1
   if(str.length % 2 == 0) {
    return str.charAt(position) + str.charAt(position + 1)
    }
   if(str.length % 2 != 0) {
    return str.charAt(position)
   }
  }
```

let midle = midleCharacter('hola') // ol
let midle = midleCharacter('cosas') // s

Comment: No suele ser una buena práctica utilizar varios return dentro de una función, podrías tener una variable result por ejemplo a la cual le asignes el resultado dentro de cada if, y al final un único return, tampoco son necesarios los 2 if, podrías utilizar un if/else y por último podrías utilizar algo como un operador ternario. Dejo código al final de mi respuesta.